# How to turn off anti-aliasing on an embedded font

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, fonts, embedded-fonts

I have a pixel font from www.fontsforflash.com. I have embedded it using flex then loaded the swf in flash CS4 to make it available. But its very blurry and I can find a way to turn off anti-aliasing in as3.

Its the right size and placed with whole numbers. The reason I have embedded this method is because I don't want to load an entire font library.

Is there a way I can turn off anti-aliasing or is there a better way to embed my font?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was trying to do this just via actionscript though, because when you embed via the library you get the entire character set. But there doesn't seem to be a way to set to bitmap when you import using the embed tag. What I have done is embedded on the stage then then utilise the internal name (fontname_8pt_st). That seems the best method as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

when you embed your font make sure you select the "bitmap text" check box in the Font Symbol Properties panel (in Flash) to insure the font has no anti-alias.

i don't recall if CS4 had this option, but in Flash CS5 you can select View > Snapping > Snap To Pixels so that all of your placed assets will have rounded x and y coordinates.  it will do the same thing as the code posted by PatrickS.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a pixel font , don't forget that the x & y values must be integers. You'll probably need to do something like this.

```
textfield.x = Math.round( whateverX );
textfield.y = Math.round( whateverY );
```

and probably the same thing for the parent!